# Is it possible to use Following and preceding in combination in Selenium?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]On this page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Seven#Episode_list
I have:

```
//*[text()='Reception']//preceding::th[contains(@id, 'ep')]//following::I
```

But it only registers following.

The default firepath selector is: `.//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[1]/I` but this kind of selector is known to break quite frequently.  Just wondering if there is a better way of doing this and I thought this might be a way.

Thanks!
:)
- You can see that it's getting stuff under the table which is not what I want :S

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to get two elements at the same time?

Comment: What is your exact manual step? Which element on the HTML DOM are you trying to `locate` / `click()` / `getText()`? Thanks

Comment: @Andersson I am not sure what you are asking sorry :S.  I am wanting to get all the highlighted elements in the table you can see in the picture.  So preceding the reception text and following ep number

Comment: @DebanjanB See where it says like number 5 and then you can see the highlighted tab in firepath.  I want Firepath to get all of that in the table and not any other stuff outside of the table.  I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @DebanjanB get text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath` to match required elements:

```
//th[contains(@id, 'ep')]/following::I[./following::*[text()='Reception']]
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome!  Exactly what I wanted.  I'm going to study that so I can replicate this in the future.  Any good books/guides you'd recommend on mastering xpath?   Thanks heaps!! :)

Comment: @DebanjanB If you want you can still include what you were going to put.  Although you won't get awarded points sorry :S

Comment: @DebanjanB So it was a combined effort of mentor and mentee then?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks more simple

```
//tr[contains(@class, 'vevent')]//i
```

Don't overcomplicate things. You need `I` tag inside each row. So just find row locator `tr[contains(@class, 'vevent')]` and get it's `I`

Another good approach in case you want to check that inside of parent element is located some special element, but you want to find some 3rd element is to use such style: `//element[./specific]//child` , so in your case:

```
//tr[contains(@class, 'vevent')][./th[contains(@id,'ep')]]//i
```

so it's `I` tag inside row that contains `@id,'ep'` in header

Comment: Thanks for sharing :).  I'm definitely going to use this method as well.

Comment: Thanks ^.^.  I feel a lot more confident about extracting this page now.

Comment: Cool) The point is - always look to wrapper elements, as they are usually nice structured and has some nice classes/attributes. And inner elements - are just spans/divs/etc without any proper indicators. That's why locators become more simple and readable when you are moving from parent element to some child comparing to complex  /following/preciding locators